# Laravel 5.2 url's not working without index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes, laravel-5

I have a laravel 5.2 project in my localhost and its url's are not working without index.php. I have renamed server.php file into index.php in project root directory and copied .htaccess file from public to project root directory. The project landing page is showing fine. But when i access the url's like http://localhost/project_folder/home is redirecting into 404 not found page. When i tried to access the url's with index.php (http://localhost/project_folder/index.php/login) its working fine.

Here is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Have you set route for Home ?

Comment: yes. it's there

Comment: would be really great if you can put some code here so I can understand what you're doing

Comment: Okay. There is no code changes in .htaccess or routes.php file. I just changed server.php into index.php in project root directory and copied .htaccess file from public to project root directory.I have modified my question with .htacess file

Comment: Route::auth();
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
 Route::get('/','HomeController@index');
 Route::get('/home','HomeController@index');
});

user something like that in your route file to mention home route

Comment: I have tried the codes in route file. But it's still giving 404 not found error.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You should also not do this in productive enviroment. Instead setup a virtual host for your local development. It's easier and it's closer to what it will be in a productive env.

Comment: Actually the issue was with my virtual host file. I have modified the virtual host file in /etc/apache2/apache.conf file and added allow permissions. Then its worked  fine now. Thank you guys...